# Calculating, in best performance, distance between two lat,lng points, given short distance (max 10km)

Tags: mysql, latitude-longitude

Given two lat, lng points that I know that the distance between those is maximum 10KM, do I have to use haversine formula to calculate the distance between the points or is there a simpler way (assume earth is flat) that would get me to almost the same result but in better performance?

Comment: Haversine is fine, but to improve performance, include a 10k bounding box.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just "calculating" distance of a few items?  Or are you "searching for all within 10km?  There is a huge difference.

The latter is really an algorithm problem of how to shoehorn a 2D problem into a 1D indexing mechanism.

Plan A:  No relevant index -- must check all rows.

Plan B:  `INDEX(lat), INDEX(lng)` and use a "bounding box":  `WHERE lat BETWEEN... AND lng BETWEEN...` -- The optimizer will pick one or the other index.

Plan C:  If you have millions of rows, say so; there is a faster (but more [complex](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng)) way.

I have not answered your question because it is the least important part of the algorithm.  But I will answer it now.

Haversine takes about twice as long as flat-earth plus Pythagoras.  *But that is just for the computation; fetching the rows is far more significant in the processing*.

Haversine is not necessary for such a small distance.  I think it even works 'correctly' when crossing the dateline or a pole.  I suspect flat-earth has trouble at those edge cases.

With flat-earth, be sure to divide longitude difference by `COS(RADIANS(deg))`.  (1 degree longitude is half as far in Helsinki (at 60deg latitude) as at the Equator.)